# How to make image with blank backround

Tags: adobe-photoshop

When the backround is erased in photoshop how can i save the picture without backround, because if i save it with no backround later the image is with white backround.?

Comment: Does [What web graphics formats to use?](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/41/52050) answer your question?

Comment: If you save your document normally - as a PSD, Photoshop's native format - there is no reason at all to see the transparency lost. So you clearly save as something else. As what?

Comment: I want to save it in image format not photoshop format.

Comment: Photoshop PSD *is* an image format! If you add for what purpose you want to save it, we could be of more help.

Comment: PSD is an image format but it's not supported on most of image visualizers, the purpose of this format is to save layer information and can only be used on Adobe software. It's not intended to be the final image product

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using Adobe Photoshop the transparency is going to look like a checkered texture on your image. If you save as a .png file the transparency it's going to be maintained if your settings say so.

Example: I took off the background of this drawing:

[image]

Then I saved as a .png  file with this settings:

[image]

When you drag the image from your folder you can see its transparency.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can save it as a png. That will preserve the transparent parts.

Comment: But saving normally, as a PSD, should also do that.