# Which image format to use for IMPORTED images while creating web design assets

Tags: website-design, image-format, web-standards

Very basic questions, but I still do not have a clear understanding on it.

Let's say that I need to create web assets (banners, social media posts, etc.) and I need to import product pictures and lifestyle pictures in them.

Should I import the huge original .tiff and .psd files or can I import their sized down .png or .jpg versions?

I usually use Photoshop to do this.

Thanks!

Comment: JPG, PNG or GIF

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What web graphics formats to use?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/41/what-web-graphics-formats-to-use)

Answer (score 1):

Speaking of **importing** I typically will use the best quality image I have. If that's a .tif or .psd I use that and then convert it to a smart object while I work on the design for the banner/asset/whatever.

It's typically best to start with the highest possible value, then export/save to the lower quality for the web.

You really **never** want to save a jpg as a jpg. You can *dramatically* reduce image quality that way. (PNGs not so much)

**So import the best images you have, design your pieces, then save/export as jpg/png/gif for the web.**

Comment: Thanks @scott. And why do you convert the imported files to a smart object?

Comment: @Nora as a **Smart Object** I can feel free to reduce, then enlarge or transform while *always* referencing the *original image quality* and not be concerned with interpolation of the image. That way if I mistakenly reduce something too much, I am okay if I need to enlarge it again as long as I never enlarge to a size greater than the image originally was.